# how to get #define symbol rather than value from predefine constants

Tags: c++

I have one C++ define statement as:

```
#define PING 10
```

In my `main` function, I have something like:

```
int main()
{
    int code;
    cout<<"enter command code";
    cin>>code;      // value entered 10
    cout<<code;   //here i want "PING" output instead of 10
                
    return 0;
}
```

How can I replace 10 with PING in my output?

#### Edit:

i will have multiple #define as

```
#define PING 10
#define STATUS 20
#define FETCH 74
#define ACK 12
#define TRAIL 9
#define EXIT 198
```

now my bussiness logic will get only command code i.e 10 or 12 etc etc

i want to retreive corresponding command name for that code..how is it possible??

Comment: Neither `PING` nor `10` is an l-value.

Comment: Good point, @Als, modded question to suit.

Comment: yeah exactly..thumbs up for this point..just want to know how to get left side value of #define

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about replacing:

```
cout << code;
```

with:

```
if (code == PING)
    cout << "PING";
else
    cout << code;
```

That's the easiest way if you have a single `#define`. For more complicated cases, you could have an array of strings to look up, based on the `#define` values, something like:

```
#define E_OK        0
#define E_NOMEM     1
#define E_BADFILE   2
#define E_USERERROR 3
#define E_NEXT_ERR  4

static const char *errStr[] = {
    "Okay",
    "No memory left",
    "Bad file descriptor",
    "User is insane",
};
:
if ((errCode < 0) || (errCode >= E_NEXT_ERR))
    cout << "Unknown error: " << errCode << '\n';
else
    cout << "Error: " << errStr[errCode] << '\n';
```

If the values are disparate, you can opt for a non-array-based solution, such as:

```
#define PING 10
#define STATUS 20
#define FETCH 74
#define ACK 12
#define TRAIL 9
#define EXIT 198
:
const char *toText (int errCode) {
    if (errCode == PING  ) return "Ping";
    if (errCode == STATUS) return "Status";
    if (errCode == FETCH ) return "Fetch";
    if (errCode == ACK   ) return "Ack";
    if (errCode == TRAIL ) return "Trail";
    if (errCode == EXIT  ) return "Exit";
                           return "No idea!";
}
```

---

The other thing you *may* want to consider doing is replacing `#define` values with enumerated constants. It may not matter for simple things like this but the type safety and extra information provided will almost certainly ease your debugging efforts at some point in your career.

Nowadays, I generally only use `#define` for conditional compilation. Constants are better done with enumerations and it's been a long time since I could out-think compilers on what should and shouldn't be an inline function :-)

Comment: nice...something like if(errCode=isdefine) return corresponding string....possible?

Comment: @james: No. In general, C++ symbols and defines are not included in the executable. Strings are.

Answer (score 2):

PING as you have defined is a preprocessor macro.
It will simply be replaced by 10 at all occurrences of PING.

To print PING in place of 10, you will need to store the string "PING" somewhere so that you can print it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the lvalue of a preprocessor directive, because `#define` works before the compilation and simply replaces all occurrences of `PING` in the code with `10`. So if you write, for example, `if(code == PING)`, then, before the compilation starts, the preprocessor will replace it with `if(code == 10)`, and obviously 10 is an rvalue.

In your case you can do this:

```
int main()
{
    int code;
    cout<<"enter command code";
    cin>>code;      
    if( code == PING )
        cout<<code;   
    else 
        cout<<code;

    return 0;
}
```